# "Failed to load [localhost] resource" when deploying Flex as web-application

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a `Flex` app and when I embed it in a web application the images stop showing.

This is how I use images in code:

```
<s:BitmapImage source="assets/images/components/dropdown-down-arrow-only.png" id="arrow"
                   verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

I have the app in /Content/flex/app.swf and the error I get in console when I open the page is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:36869/app/Create/assets/images/components/dropdown-down-arrow-only.png
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your relative path correct?

Comment: @NicolasSiver Images are displayed correctly when I run the application from Flash Builder

Comment: "localhost" resources are *only* available from the *local* machine (as when developing), but not from remote clients. So that is the problem .. but I don't know how to fix it. Good luck!